# Data not persisted into database using Spring DATA

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring data to save my data into a database. I wrote a test case. It runs perfectly but doesn't insert data into the database.

**DatabaseTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebAppConfig.class, PersistenceConfig.class, 
SecurityConfig.class, PropertyPlaceholderConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration

@Transactional
public class DatabaseTest {

@Autowired private UsersRepository usersRepository;
@Autowired private LoginsRepository loginsRepository;
@Test
public void saveOne2One(){
    Logins lgn = new Logins();
    lgn.setUserName("userName");
    lgn.setPasswordHash("dfaskjdfaksjfdalksdf");

    Users usr = new Users();
    usr.setFirstName("test");
    usr.setLastName("last");
    usr.setUserName("userName");

    usr.setLogins(lgn);
    lgn.setUsers(usr);
    loginsRepository.save(lgn);
    //usersRepository.save(usr);
    loginsRepository.flush();
}
}
```

**Users.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users", schema = "abcd")
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 5074527544635474973L;
private Long userId;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String userName;
private Logins logins;

public Users() {
}

public Users(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public Users(Long userId, String firstName, String lastName,
        String userName, Logins logins) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.userName = userName;

    this.logins = logins;

}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
public Long getUserId() {
    return this.userId;
}

public void setUserId(Long userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

@Column(name = "first_name")
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

@Column(name = "last_name")
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

@Column(name = "user_name")
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}
}
```

**Logins.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "logins", schema = "abcd")
public class Logins implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3093763378845870599L;
private Long loginId;
private Users users;
private String userName;
//private String passwordSalt;
private String passwordHash;

public Logins() {
}

public Logins(Long loginId) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
}

public Logins(Long loginId, Users users, String userName,
         String passwordHash) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
    this.users = users;
    this.userName = userName;
    //this.passwordSalt = passwordSalt;
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "login_id", nullable = false)
public Long getLoginId() {
    return this.loginId;
}

public void setLoginId(Long loginId) {
    this.loginId = loginId;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "related_user_id")
public Users getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}

public void setUsers(Users users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Column(name = "user_name")
public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}


@Column(name = "password_hash", length=60)
public String getPasswordHash() {
    return this.passwordHash;
}

public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
}

}
```

The underlying tables were created like this:

**abcd.logins**

```
CREATE TABLE abcd.logins
(
login_id bigint,
user_name text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
password_salt text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
password_hash text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
related_user_id bigint
)
```

**abcd.users**

```
CREATE TABLE abcd.users
(
user_id bigint,
first_name text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
last_name text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog,
user_name text COLLATE "default".pg_catalog
)
```

I am unable to find out the reason for data not getting persisted into database. I even invoked `flush()` method of repository but to no avail. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You can add @Rollback(false) for specific test if you don't want to rollback transaction.
In your case I hope that you've committed transaction using `commit` method.

In your case:

```
@Test
@Rollback(false)
public void saveOne2One(){
    Logins lgn = new Logins();
    lgn.setUserName("userName");
    lgn.setPasswordHash("dfaskjdfaksjfdalksdf");

    Users usr = new Users();
    usr.setFirstName("test");
    usr.setLastName("last");
    usr.setUserName("userName");

    usr.setLogins(lgn);
    lgn.setUsers(usr);
    loginsRepository.save(lgn);
    //usersRepository.save(usr);
    loginsRepository.flush();
}
```

or if you want to persist data for all tests(class level) without rollback then you can use: 
`@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)`

Answer (score 1):

You execute a junit Test with @Transaction, see [Spring Testing Transaction management](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/testing.html#testing-tx) but by default, the framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test.

> If you want a transaction to commit - unusual, but occasionally useful when you want a particular test to populate or modify the database - the TestContext framework can be instructed to cause the transaction to commit instead of roll back via the @TransactionConfiguration and @Rollback annotations.